# Node - trying to find and filter an array of objects that fall into today's timeline (timestamps)

Tags: node.js, datetime, momentjs

I've got a CSV file that I'm converting to an array of objects. All events (rows) have a timestamp beginning and end. I'm trying to perform a search for all of todays events. I'm looking at moment.js to do this, but, running into errors when searching.

The data looks like this. NOTE: The data set is older so I'm trying to spoof a 'today' variable for August 5th 2019, which is in the range of events that day

```
{
            "T_START": "1565019000",
            "T_END": "1565023500",
            "PROJECT": "Billionaire",

        },
        {
            "T_START": "1565024400",
            "T_END": "1565028000",
            "PROJECT": "John's Place",

        },
        {
            "T_START": "1565024400",
            "T_END": "1565029800",
            "PROJECT": "The Smith Show",

        }
```

And here's my code so far. With this, I'm getting an empty array but a 200 success case

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Get schedules from CSV File
        let schedules = await csv().fromFile(getCsv('scheduallworkorders.csv'));

        // Check for query strings
        if (req.query.search == 'today') {
            // Get todays schedules

            // Get date
            let today = moment('08-05-2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY');

            // Filter for today
            let todaysSchedules = schedules.filter(value => {
                return moment(value.T_START).isBetween(
                    today,
                    today,
                    null,
                    '[]'
                );
                //return value.T_START == today;
            });

            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Success getting todays schedules',
                schedules: todaysSchedules
            });
        }

        // Default - Get all schedules
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Success getting all schedules',
            schedules: schedules
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error getting all schedules',
            error: error
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick

```js
let todaysSchedules = schedules.filter(value => {
  return moment(parseInt(value.T_START)*1000).isSame(today,"day")
})
```

### edit

or maybe this if you want the date of today to be within T_START and T_END

```js
let todaysSchedules = schedules.filter(value => {
  return today.isBetween(
    parseInt(value.T_START)*1000,
    parseInt(value.T_END)*1000,
    "day",
    "[]"
  )
});
```

Comment: Thanks, getting an empty array. This feels like it should work, using the second option you provided. value.T_START does return all the values in the found array but the option to filter based on todays timeline isn't working. Here's my node output. ```

Comment: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 1564938000, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

Comment: Ok i found the why of the warning and corrected the code.

Comment: https://repl.it/@gui3/datesBetween?language=nodejs  you will see that your dates in T_START and T_END are not Epoch miliseconds... this is a problem

Comment: found the issue, they are in seconds instead of miliseconds, just *1000

Comment: @mikevarela now it works in my replit, should work in your situation

Comment: That finally worked. Had to multiply the original 'today' by 1000 to make it work as well. Thanks so much!!!!